# Hiding all worksheets error: "Method 'Visible' of object'_Worksheet' failed"

Tags: excel, vba

There are around 10 worksheets in my workbook.

I want to make the two worksheets left and the remaining worksheets hide.

```vb
Sub Hide_sheet()

    Dim sht As Worksheet
    
    For Each sht In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
        
        If sht.Name <> "Jason" Or sht.Name <> "Mary" Then
        
            sht.Visible = False
        
        End If
        
    Next sht
    
End Sub
```

I got an error

> Method 'Visible' of object'_Worksheet' failed

Comment: Shouldn’t the `or` be an `and` otherwise the test for Jason or Mary will always be True, and you will hide all sheets regardless.

Comment: Dear DS_London, yes you are right...a simple mistake i made....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error is because you are trying to hide the last visible sheet, and you cannot have 0 visible sheets.

Add a count check to prevent that:

```
Sub Hide_sheet()
    Dim sht As Worksheet
    
    Dim nCount As Integer
    nCount = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets.Count
    
    For Each sht In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
        If sht.Name <> "Jason" And sht.Name <> "Mary" Then
            If nCount > 1 Then
                nCount = nCount - 1
                sht.Visible = False
            End If
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

If there is no "Jason" or "Mary" sheet, then you will be left with one worksheet that has its default name. How you handle that situation is up to you.

Comment: Thanks braX, you had perfectly help me to solved this question. I will remember to prevent hide the last visible sheet.